# How do I change the color of a link in Elm?

Tags: elm

I create links for a website in Elm with `Text.link "https://somewebsite.com" (toText "SomeWebsite")`. I would like to be able to set the color of the resultant text.

I have tried `Text.link "https://somewebsite.com" (Text.color white <|toText "SomeWebsite")` and `Text.color white <|Text.link "https://somewebsite.com" (toText "SomeWebsite")`, neither of which work, despite that the type signature of `link` is `link : String -> Text -> Text`. Both of these snippets compile.

I've looked through the source of elm-lang.org, which has links that look like they've been styled (they seem to have a different color than the default dark blue and no underlines) and haven't found anything that explains how it's done there.

How can I color the text of links in Elm?

Comment: You can just use CSS, right? Not trying to be condescending, it looks a a gap in the knowledge of the original asker. This would be far more annoying to do in Elm than in your site's stylesheet, but the other responses covered that too. It's the web, so you have to do it in CSS, even if you put the CSS in Elm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will create a link to google that is red:

```
import Text (..)

main = toText "Google" 
    |> style  {defaultStyle | color <- red, height <- Just 20 } 
    |> link "http://google.com"
    |> leftAligned
```

Live demo [here](http://share-elm.com/sprout/53a0418be4b07afa6f9820b9).

Unfortunately, this does not give you the power to really "style" the link when you hover over it which is a bit of a bummer.

The elm-lang website has the following styles at the top of its pages:

```
<style type="text/css">
  a:link {text-decoration: none; color: rgb(15,102,230);}
  a:visited {text-decoration: none}
  a:active {text-decoration: none}
  a:hover {text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(234,21,122);}
  body { font-family: "Lucida Grande","Trebuchet MS","Bitstream Vera Sans",Verdana,Helvetica,sans-serif !important; }
  p, li { font-size: 14px !important;
          line-height: 1.5em !important; }
</style>
```

This gives its links the styling you see there.

However, it is still possible to get this type of styling using [`customButton`](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/elm-lang-Elm/0.12.3/Graphics-Input#customButton) from `Graphics.Input`.

```
import Graphics.Input as Input

click = Input.input ()

linkFormat = { defaultStyle | color <- blue }
hoverFormat = { linkFormat | bold <- True }

customLink url text = 
    let text' = Text.toText text
        regular = Text.style linkFormat text' |> leftAligned
        hover = Text.style hoverFormat text' |> leftAligned
        down = Text.style linkFormat text' |> leftAligned
    in link url <| Input.customButton click.handle () regular hover down

main = customLink "http://google.com" "Google"
```

Live demo [here](http://share-elm.com/sprout/53a0460ce4b07afa6f9820ca).

One thing to notice here is that I am not using `Text.link`. I am just using the [`link`](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/elm-lang-Elm/0.12.3/Graphics-Element#link) function from [`Graphics.Element`](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/elm-lang-Elm/0.12.3/Graphics-Element) which is imported by default and has the type `String -> Element -> Element`.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This no longer works on Elm 0.13, btw.  It first says link is ambiguous between the one in the Graphics lib and the Text.link, so I qualify it by prepending Text. to link and then it complains that it 'Could not find variable 'Text.link'.'  Same thing happens when I qualify it as a Graphics.Element.link.

it seems weird that I would not be able to qualify something by adding the module qualifier to it in Elm 0.13.

To accomplish this in 0.13, I figured out you can do the below.

```
    import Text
```

`main = link "http://www.google.com" <| leftAligned <| Text.color red <| toText "Google"`

http://share-elm.com/sprout/5430943ee4b017b21db2f86c

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://ellie-app.com/RDXpySDh25a1) in Elm-0.18

```elm
module Main exposing (main)

import Html as H exposing (Html)
import Html.Attributes as HA


main : Html msg
main =
    H.a
        [ HA.href "https://en.wikipedia.org"
        , HA.style [ ( "color", "green" ) ]
        ]
        [ H.text "wikipedia" ]
```